# How to make VIM settings computer-dependent in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, operating-systems, vimrc, dependencies

I share my VIM configuration file between several computers. However, I want some settings to be specific for certain computers.

For example, font sizes on the high-res laptop should be different to the low-res desktop. And more importantly, I want gVIM on Windows to behave more windowsy and MacVim on OSX to behave more maccy and gVIM on Linux to just behave like it always does. (That might be a strange sentiment, but I am very used to switch mental modes when switching OSes)

Is there a way to make a few settings in the `.vimrc` machine- or OS-dependent?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

OS detection in `.vimrc`:

```
if has('win32')
    ......
elseif has('mac')
    ......
elseif has('unix')
    ......
endif
```

Comment: Also useful: `has('gui_running')` if you need to differentiate between tty mode and GUI mode.

Comment: The has() function tests the presence of Vim features. There is no 'linux' feature. The proper argument is 'unix'. Also, the proper argument for OS-X is 'macunix'. There is also a 'mac' feature, but I don't know whether `has('mac')` is true for all Macs or just pre-OS-X Macs. See `:help feature-list` for the full list.

Comment: Yes, `has('unix')`. My mistake.

Comment: A very late answer, but yes, has('mac') triggers in OSX for me.

Comment: I've tested vim 1) that comes with OS X, and 2) that I installed via Gentoo Prefix (something similar to Homebrew), and 3) that comes from MacVim. Only the one comes from MacVim will correctly return true for `has("mac")`. My guess is that they used some patch that actually make the feature test work. If you do rely on `has("mac")` test, do some test to make sure it's supported on your vim.

Comment: Note that you have to test `has('mac')` and `has('unix')` in the order above, because a Mac also has unix!

Answer (score 28):

To test for a particular machine, you can test the output of the `hostname` command. For example,

```
let hostname = substitute(system('hostname'), '\n', '', '')
if hostname == "tigger"
   ...
elseif hostname == "pooh"
   ...
endif
```

You could also test the value of available environment variables:

```
if $HOSTNAME == "tigger"
   ...
elseif $HOSTNAME == "pooh"
   ...
endif
```

The `$DISPLAY` variable can also be useful.

Comment: hostname() will do this, eg: if hostname() == 'tigger'..., without having to make the system call.

Comment: The result for `system('hostname')` was `machine.mycompany.com\n`, so I had to change the substitute command to `substitute(system('hostname'), '\.\_.*$', '', '')`.

Answer (score 9):

I have this snippet in my `vimrc`:

```
let s:host_vimrc = $HOME . '/.' . hostname() . '.vimrc'                                                                                                                               
if filereadable(s:host_vimrc)                                                                                                                                                        
  execute 'source ' . s:host_vimrc                                                                                                                                                   
endif
```

This simply executes `source $HOME/.$HOSTNAME.vimrc` if it exists.  I've used `hostname()` and concatenation, you could also use the more succinct `expand('$HOME/.$HOSTNAME.vimrc')` if you know that `$HOSTNAME` is always set.

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer about OS detection does not detect OS X in MacVim for me (and neither does using `has("macunix")` as the documentation suggests it should).

Here's what I use to distiguish between Windows and OS X:

```
if has("win32")
  "Windows options here
else
  if has("unix")
    let s:uname = system("uname")
    if s:uname == "Darwin\n"
      "Mac options here
    endif
  endif
endif
```

Note that `has("win32")` worked for me, even in 64 bit Vim on 64 bit Windows.

You could also use similar tests of `uname` within the `if has("unix")` block to distinguish other flavours of Unix. Just run `uname` or `uname -a` from the command-line to see what you need to compare `s:uname with`. See also `:h matchstr()` if you need to compare just a part of uname's output.

Answer (score 3):

With a lot of machines, listing all hostnames in `.vimrc` can become tedious, it might be easier to distinguish between different unix flavors:

```
" set font when running on Solaris
if (match(system('uname -s'), 'SunOS') >= 0)  
   set guifont=*   " fixes "E665: Cannot start GUI, no valid font found"
endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks on windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

You could just put the OS-specific stuff in a custom .gvimrc for each machine, and use a common .vimrc on all of them. Both files are read when GVim starts, only .vimrc is read when the non-gui Vim starts.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding separation between Linux and Windows - you can simply put different settings in `.vimrc` and `_vimrc`, accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
if $COMPUTERNAME == "COMPUTER1"

settings here

elseif $COMPUTERNAME == "COMPUTER2"

settings here

endif
```

Comment: Your comment lacks the information necessary to make it an answer. The question is 11 years old and already answered. Your post must include sufficient information to add significant additional value to make this worth the post.